# Why global pointer changes it's value after return from function?

Tags: c

I am setting value of a global pointer to a local variable as shown below. global pointer's value is correct in function scope but goes back to NULL once execution returns from function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *addr = NULL;

char* date(){
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    char* text = asctime(localtime(&now));
    text[strlen(text) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("addr -%p :%s\n", addr, addr);
    char* addr = text;
    printf("addr -%p :%s\n", addr, addr);
    return text;
}

int main(){
    char* date_text = date();
    printf("text -%p :%s\n", date_text, date_text);
    printf("addr -%p :%s\n", addr, addr);
    return 0;
}
```

As per my understanding value of addr pointer should be same of returned pointer(date_text) or text. However it goes back to NULL after return. Where am i getting it wrong
I see following output in my machine

```
addr -(nil) :(null)
addr -0x7f3927ce0b20 :Sun Dec 15 15:41:41 2019
text -0x7f3927ce0b20 :Sun Dec 15 15:41:41 2019
addr -(nil) :(null)
```

Comment: You're assigning `text` to a ___local___ pointer `addr`.

Comment: ahh shoot,I could not be more silly

Comment: Printing a null pointer with `%s` has undefined behaviour. It can crash your program, unlearn this habit. Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and you will get errors for shadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redifining a ***local*** version of `*addr` here:

```
printf("addr -%p :%s\n", addr, addr);
char* addr = text; // <--
printf("addr -%p :%s\n", addr, addr);
```

This [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global version. Remove the `char*`, and you'll receive the needed behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

`char* addr = text;`

in this line `addr` is a **local variable** *shadowing* the global variable. So, no, you are not changing the global one. Replace the line with

`addr = text;`

for changing the global variable.